# php horizontal menu design breaks for first element?

Tags: html, css

Can anybody tell me why the design breaks for first element in the menu?

Here is the code for.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down menu in php</title>
<link href="css/menustyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
                <li><img src="logo.png"></li>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Forms</li>
                <li><a href="#">Databases</li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Account</li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>


<style type="text/css">
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: because your markup is invalid and you dont close your `<a>` tags

Answer (score 4):

You are not closing any of the `a` tag in your markup

```
<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                         ----^----
```

Comment: I tried it but there is no effect.

Comment: @Hitendra You are doing something wrong http://jsfiddle.net/uP5Be/

Comment: @Alien i copy code from the link for both css and html but same result.It looks good in the given link. Can you guess what could be the reason?

Comment: @Hitendra Are you populating elements using PHP?

Comment: @Hitendra See the generated source markup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29575/discussion-between-hitendra-and-mr-alien)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle for your solution :

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/TzXZf/)

The problem with anchor tag closing only.

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><img src="logo.png"/></li>
   <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php">Forms</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Databases</a></li>
   <li><a href="login.php">Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Don't format the link -1, share your code and I'll take back -1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174690/users-fooling-stackoverflow-by-highlighting-jsfiddle-links-instead-of-an-actual

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the css rule for the img tag as well.

You have:

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but you also need:

```
ul li img {
    Some CSS for the img block
}
```

In your css...

Comment: I tried it and it changes the background of an image to blue but didnt solve my query.

Comment: It was a suggested improvement to the design to add css for the img in that context as well, the closing if the tags was of course what you needed to not break the layout, but as for the "design" (style of the presentation) you need to apply a css rule that contains the presentation for the img-tag as well, otherwise if you change the image and it has different properties, your "design" may present it self in an unwanted fashion. I saw that you have specified how you like your child a to behave, but not the child img in the li.